# Как добавить строку в начало файла csv?

Tags: python, файлы, csv

У меня есть файл csv

```
,text,text,text
0,text,text,text
1,text,text,text
```

Как мне перед запятой в 1 строке добавить слово NUM?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file.csv', "r+") as f:
    data = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write('NUM' + data)
```